# Python number guessing game

Tags: python, beginner, number-guessing-game

I'm a PHP Developer. I'm trying to learn Python. So I tried to create a simple game, a Number Guesser.

I tried to comment out as much as possible without making super obvious comments.

I also made the `attempts` message color to be red.

Here's my code.

```
# 1. Print a message about the game
# 2. Tell the user that the random number is between some numbers
# 3. Run a while loop to continue the input, break the loop when the guess is right.
# 4`. When the user guessed the number, tell them that they're right.

import random

# Simple message to the user.
print "Welcome to the Number Guesser game."
print "I have a number in my mind that's between 1-20."

number = random.randint(0, 20)

# Guess the number
# > 
prompt = "> "

# Start out as 5 and then decrement it on wrong guesses.
attempts = 5


while attempts > 0:
    print "What's your guess? "

    # Simple validation
    try:
        guess = int(raw_input(prompt))
    except ValueError: 
        print "Only numbers are allowed. \n"
        break

    if guess > number:
        print "Go lower."
    elif guess < number:
        print "Go higher."
    else:
        print "Nice! You've guessed it right. The number was %d." % number
        print "And you got it with %d attempts!" % attempts
        # Exit.
        break

    # Decrement the attempts each time the guess isn't right.
    attempts -= 1


    if attempts == 0:
        print "You didn't guessed it, the number was %d. You lose." % number
        # Exit the script.
        break
    # Print with the color red.
    print("\033[91m You have {} guesses left. \033[00m").format(attempts)
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> number = random.randint(0, 20)
> ```

You just told the user that the number is between one and twenty, but you use `random.randint(0, 20)`.  What if the result was `0`?  One disgruntled player.  You should be using `number = random.randint(1, 20)`.

> ```
> prompt = "> "
> ```

You aren't hard-coding the value.  That's very good.  Since it is a constant, however, you should use `ALLCAPS`.

> ```
> attempts = 5
> while attempts > 0:
> ```

You are starting out at the high point and decrementing until you get to zero.  That isn't really the number of attempts.  That is how many attempts are left.  I would define a constant for the number of attempts allowed, define `attempts` as `0`, and have the `while` make sure that `attempts` is lower than that number.  This becomes especially useful when printing how many attempts it took.  As it is, your program displays the wrong number: the number of attempts that were left.

> ```
> try:
>     guess = int(raw_input(prompt))
> except ValueError: 
>     print "Only numbers are allowed. \n"
>     break
> ```

It's good that you try to validate the input, but you should use `continue` instead of `break`.  One invalid input shouldn't end the program.

> ```
> print "Nice! You've guessed it right. The number was %d." % number
> ```

Using `%` for a format string isn't officialy deprecated, but it is recommended to use `.format()`.

What if the user wants to play again?  You make him re-run the script.  I would use a `while` loop and a function:

```
import random

PROMPT = "> "
GUESSES = 5

def guess_number(start=1, end=20):
    print "I have a number in my mind that's between {}-{}.".format(start, end)
    number = random.randint(start, end)
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < GUESSES:
        print "What's your guess? "

        # Simple validation
        try:
            guess = int(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError: 
            print "Only numbers are allowed. \n"
            continue

        if guess > number:
            print "Go lower."
        elif guess < number:
            print "Go higher."
        else:
            print "Nice! You've guessed it right. The number was {:d}.".format(number)
            print "And you got it with {:d} attempts!".format(attempts + 1)
            break

        # Increment the attempts each time the guess isn't right.
        attempts += 1


        if attempts == GUESSES:
            print "You didn't guess it; the number was {:d}. You lose.".format(number)
            break
        # Print with the color red.
        print("\033[91m You have {} guesses left. \033[00m").format(attempts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Welcome to the Number Guesser game."

    again = True
    while again:
        print "I have a number in my mind that's between 1-20."
        guess_number()
        play_again = raw_input("Would you like to play again? ")
        while play_again.lower() not in "yn":
            play_again = raw_input("Invalid input. [y/n] ")
        again = (play_again.lower() == "y")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say to go with what zondo said, except that you should probably get rid of the extra check for attempts == GUESSES.

> ```
> if attempts == GUESSES:
>       print "...the number was {:d}. Youlose.".format(number)
>       break
> ```

Your while loop is already checking that *attempts* is less than *GUESSES*. You can just put the ending print statement at the end of the *guess_number* function.

As it was mentioned, the function with this change will print "You lose" even if you've won. Instead of breaking out of the loop when the correct number is guessed, you can use `return` to make the function exit instead.

Also, zondo said you should use continue instead of break on invalid inputs for guesses. In case you didn't learn about the continue statement, what it will do is skip the remaining statements in the current iteration of a loop and move control back to the top of the loop.

Comment: I didn't change the first because the `while` loop ends even if the player wins.  If you put the `Youlose` just after the `while` loop, it might print it after saying that you won.

Comment: `return` can work there. Instead of breaking out of the loop when the correct number is guessed, it would make sense for the _guess_number_ function to exit.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't right now.  Perhaps you should add that instruction to your answer?